# Arangodb AQL query

Tags: optimization, graph, query-optimization, arangodb, aql

I have data organized such way:

[image]

There are 1k of teachers, 10k of pupils, every pupil has ~100 homeworks.

I need get all homeworks of pupils, related to a teacher via classes, or by direct link between them. All vertices and edges have some attributes, and let's suppose all required indices are already built, or we can discuss them a bit later.

I can get all required pupils ids by such fast enough query:

```
$query1 = "FOR v1 IN 1..1 INBOUND @teacherId teacher_pupil FILTER v1.deleted == false RETURN DISTINCT v1._id";
$query2 = "FOR v2 IN 2..2 INBOUND @teacherId OUTBOUND teacher_class, INBOUND pupil_class FILTER v2.deleted == false RETURN DISTINCT v2._id";
$queryUnion = "FOR x IN UNION_DISTINCT (($query1), ($query2)) RETURN x";
```

Then I wrote the following:

```
$query = "
LET pupilIds = ($queryUnion)

FOR pupilId IN pupilIds
    LET homeworks = (
        FOR homework IN 1..1 ANY pupilId pupil_homework
            return [homework._id, pupilId]
    )  
RETURN homeworks";
```

I got my homeworks, and I even can try filter them, but the query is too slow - that's an incorrect way, I believe.

**Question 1** How can I do it without getting all Homeworks huge amount to memory at a time (LIMIT or whatever), sorting and filtering Homeworks by vertex' attributes fast and efficient? I'm sure limiting pupils, or pupil-related homeworks in the query/subquery's FOR leads to incorrect sorting/pagination.

I did another try with pure graph AQL query:

```
$query1 = "FOR v1 IN 2..2 INBOUND @teacherId pupil_teacher, OUTBOUND pupil_homework RETURN v1._id";
$query2 = "FOR v2 IN 3..3 INBOUND @teacherId teacher_class, pupil_class, OUTBOUND pupil_homework RETURN v2._id";
$query = "FOR x IN UNION_DISTINCT (($query1), ($query2)) LIMIT 500, 500 RETURN x";
```

It isn't much faster, and I don't know how filter Teacher vertices by attributes.

**Question 2** What approach is the best for building such AQL queries, how can I access vertices of a graph filtering all path's parts by attributes? Can I paginate the result to save memory and speedup the query? How can I speed up it at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming teacher and pupil are related to each other via classes(2 outbound links) or directly(single outbound link) and **with no other** way you can do something like this

```
 FOR v IN 1..2 OUTBOUND "teacher_id" GRAPH "graph_name"
   FILTER LIKE(v._id, "pupil_collection_name/%")
     FOR homeworks IN 1 OUTBOUND v GRAPH "graph_name"
        LIMIT lowerLimit,numberOfItems
           RETURN homeworks
```

But if there is a possibility that a teacher and pupil can be related to each other with something other than a class we would have to filter our query with respect to the edge we are seeing as well

```
 FOR v IN 1..2 OUTBOUND "teacher_id" GRAPH "graph_name"
   FILTER LIKE(v._id, "pupil_collection_name/%") && (e.name == "ClassPupil" || e.name == "TeacherPupil")
     FOR homeworks IN 1 OUTBOUND v GRAPH "graph_name"
        LIMIT lowerLimit,numberOfItems
           RETURN homeworks
```

Note that since same teacher can be related to a pupil directly as well as via a class, we can have non unique homeworks . Hence using a `RETURN DISTINCT homeworks` is suggested. But if duplications are not a problem, the above query should work

Comment: Thank you for the answer: the query is very fast.
What if I want filter by homework attribute? Just adding
...
FOR homeworks IN 1 OUTBOUND v GRAPH "graph_name"
        **FILTER homeworks.attr1 == 'value1'**
        LIMIT lowerLimit,numberOfItems
           RETURN homeworks
...
is too slow, and, as I know, for graph queries ArangoDB doesn't uses vertex attributes indexes.

Comment: If you just want to filter homework by homework attribute , you can simple loop in the homework collection without the need of using a graph query.
`FOR hw in home_work_collection_name FILTER hw.attr1 == 'value1' return hw` . Further, it is suggested that you index your collection by the `attr1` attribute. Once you have your filtered homework, you can traverse the graph and get the information of teacher or classes accordingly.

Conversely (suggested) you can add a `filter` in the query that is in the answer above. Just above the `LIMIT lowerLimit,numberOfItems` line